# Hazelcast file upload from client to server

Tags: java, hazelcast

What is the best way to upload a file from hazelcast client to server?
Currently, I have a web application from where users can upload a file. The file then gets put into a queue and the server has an item listener to listen when a new item gets added to the list. The problem is the item listener doesn't always get fired straight away (not sure why) so I wanted to know what was the best way to upload a file.

Comment: Listeners are asynchronous, they occur afterwards not straight away. If the system is healthy the delay is so small it will appear to be straight away. If you get something else, it will be worth finding out why.

Comment: When i load a lot of data to the cache, sometime I get heartbeat issues but the system is still working. Will the listener behave differently if it thinks it having heartbeat issues?

Comment: What version of Hazelcast ? If you've got heartbeat issues perhaps the JVM is swamped and going into GC. The server logs will usually indicate what is going on, or you can turn diagnostics on -- Hazelcast 3.9 is a good choice for diagnostics if you have flexibility to upgrade.

Comment: Well, we are loading millions of records in several caches. would this cause any issues? I am using hazelcast version 3.7.2

Comment: GC logging is the easiest way to find out. If you're approaching a capacity limit GC become obstrusive. If that's the cause, then you could evict unneeded data or add servers to increase capacity.

Comment: Seems that this is the follow-up - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711680/configuring-hazelcast-to-prevent-heartbeat-issues

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Any advice is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Observer](https://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java) design pattern as your notification mechanism.