# Configuring Hazelcast to prevent heartbeat issues

Tags: hazelcast

I am running hazelcast (3.7.2). It is split into client node and a server node. 
A client can upload files, which gets put into an IQueue to be picked up by an Item listener on the server side. The problem is, the item listeners are not picking up those items straight away because the system is "not healthy". I believe this could be due to the way memory is being used and garbage collection is struggling. This is the message I get.

```
processors=32, 
physical.memory.total=295.7G, 
physical.memory.free=2.9G, 
swap.space.total=16.0G, 
swap.space.free=15.7G, 
heap.memory.used=112.4G, 
heap.memory.free=23.3G, 
heap.memory.total=135.8G, 
heap.memory.max=135.8G, 
heap.memory.used/total=82.82%, 
heap.memory.used/max=82.82%, 
minor.gc.count=375, 
minor.gc.time=512417ms, 
major.gc.count=8, 
major.gc.time=169878ms, 
load.process=0.01%, 
load.system=0.01%, 
load.systemAverage=20.00%, 
thread.count=171, 
thread.peakCount=290, 
cluster.timeDiff=0, 
event.q.size=0, 
executor.q.async.size=0, 
executor.q.client.size=0, 
executor.q.query.size=0, 
executor.q.scheduled.size=0, 
executor.q.io.size=0, 
executor.q.system.size=0, 
executor.q.operations.size=0, 
executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, 
operations.completed.count=42173798, 
executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, 
executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, 
executor.q.cluster.size=0, 
executor.q.response.size=0, 
operations.running.count=0, 
operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, 
operations.pending.invocations.count=0, 
proxy.count=0, 
clientEndpoint.count=6, 
connection.active.count=7, 
client.connection.count=6, 
connection.count=1
Dec 08, 2017 3:39:39 AM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor
```

Can someone show me how I can optimize my configuration or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: You have 132GB of heap, GC pause time problems are inevitable. Worst case pause times are bigger the bigger the heap is. You could split this process into more smaller processes to make the impact of pause time more containable, but then if these processes have to share your 32 CPUs you get contention elsewhere. Off-heap storage is also a possibility but this is a commercial feature (it's not open source).

Comment: So if I distribute the load amongst multiple JVMs then i will get better performance?

Comment: It depends (I love this consultant like answer, you're never wrong ;-)). Joke aside, it really depends, you have plenty of cores, but you're suffering from GC issues. GC issues arise with the number of references to living objects, the more the worse (since the GC has to scan for living objects). The worse case scenario is a cache, millions of living objects. Offheap will move the cached elements out of the reach of the GC, that way GC times drop to millis. However the other option is to split the heap into multiple JVM, that way the GC has less elements to scan and is faster ....

Comment: .... however you get more contention on the CPUs and what's worse on the OS scheduler that now has to do way more work. Most probably you get faster since your biggest issue is GC times, but you get other things you need to look out for, like multiple JVMs per physical machine means backup distribution needs to be aware of that, otherwise backups might get stored on the same physical system. If that crashes, multiple JVMs are gone at the same time. It all has pros and cons. I'd recommend to have a look at HDMS (https://hazelcast.com/products/high-density-memory-store/).

Comment: Sounds like off-heap is the way to go then. In your opinion, what would be the preferred way? I'm new to this so any help and pointers are very much welcome. Also would you be using something like mongoDB to do the offheap?

Comment: Hazelcast has off-heap option for IMap and Jcache but it's in the Enterprise version. On the other hand, IQueue is not a partitioned data structure which means it will always be stored inside a single jvm even though you add more members. I'd suggest looking into IMap + MapListeners instead of using IQueue, which enables you to distribute your data to multiple servers/jvms since IMap is partitioned.